# Options page for Firefox addon using the Add-on Builder (JetPack)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox extension and want to open a **custom** html page where the user can adjust the settings. I am able to do it in different ways, but would like to use the **standard Options button** that is shown in the add-on manager of Firefox.

I have seen some documentation about it, but I am having problems on finding proper documentation for this function using the online Add-on Builder:
[Preferences system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preferences_system?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Preferences/Preferences_system),
[Inline options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Inline_Options),
[Simple prefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/simple-prefs.html).

Does anybody know how to just add that standard Options button that is shown in the add-on manager and handle its click event to show a custom options page? (just like it's possible in Google Chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Builder projects have an 'Properties' dialog that has a field you can paste the extra JSON in that you need to create preferences:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/cdb97850-935d-4cf1-95f1-a25c130d1498/4b0b2553f3aa85e4d6489c1d50492c97

( fixed the link, sorry )

Here's an example in builder that implements all the different types, and contains documentation as well:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/60337/latest/

You'll notice that one of the type of prefs you can define is a 'control' pref, essentially a button that emits a custom event you can listen of and react to from main.js. You could then open a new tab or addon-page with additional preferences?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/simple-prefs.html#prefs

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot. With this example I was able to find a workaround: put a single button in the preferences that opens a custom preferences page. However, ideally I would like to use that "Options" button of the add-on manager to directly open my custom preferences page.

Comment: Your evernote links give me "access denied". Are they accessible for registered users only?

Comment: @cprcrack: I don't think that the Add-on SDK currently supports custom preference pages. Sadly, your workaround is the best you can do.